# Symfony @ORM\Table(name="items") doesn't work

Tags: symfony, orm

I have an Entity in Symfony called "Items" and the table in the database is "items".

Here is my code:

```
namespace MoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="items")
 **/
class Items {

}
```

But `@ORM\Table(name="items")` is not working.

If I change the name of the table to "Items", it works fine (without ORM); however, I need to keep the table name in lowercase letters

What can I do here?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of error you get? What are you doing besides adding annotations to your entity?

Comment: maybe the change is not detected because items = Items, try changing your database name to btems and switch back to items lowercase.

Comment: Sorry! The error is:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Item' doesn't exist

Comment: First launch "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql" to see if you have any modification between your code and database. Later launch this to do the modifications: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: MySQL. And as I wrote below, if I use quotes, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To match the exactly same name as you specified in `@ORM\Table()` you need to wrap it with appropriate escaping quote. For example in MySQL you need next code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`items`")
 **/
class Items {

}
```

Pay attention to **`** quotes.

For PostgreSQL you need next code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="""items""")
 **/
class Items {

}
```

You can also set up your MySQL to compare table names as case insensitive but store as you declared them. To do so you need add in `my.cnf` next line:

```
[mysqld] //inside mysqld section
lower_case_table_names = 2
```

Comment: Yes, I use MySQL, but it's still not working with quotes

Comment: What type of quotes did you use? As you mentioned in comments you have error about `item` table, not `items`. Did you copied example from my answer and tried or tried it manually?

Comment: Just the same:

"An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.status AS status2 FROM Items t0':

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Item' doesn't exist
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception: PDOException »

Comment: Why it is `Item`, not `Items`? I just updated my answer where add another solution but now you need to set up your MySQL config.